# please correct my jquery toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

good night: I want to mouse over `.slide` show the `#panel`, then click the `.close` display the `#panel`, who can correct my code? thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide").mouseover(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });      
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1024px;
    height:100%;
}
#wrap {position:absolute;bottom:0px;}
#panel {
    background: #f60;
    width:600px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;  
}
.slide {
    width:600px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:#F06;
}
.close{float:right;height:20px;width:20px;background-color:#000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div class="slide">&nbsp;<div class="close">&nbsp;</div></div>
<div id="panel">
    <!-- some content -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you should use `slideToggle` in this case since it doesn't seem like `.slide` and `.close` are ever hidden

```
$(".slide").mouseover(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
$(".close").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Also, this will NEVER work until you move the `.close` div into the `#panel` since `.close` is a child of `.slide` and will trigger the `.slide` `moveover` event when you try to click `.close`

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="slide">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="close">&nbsp;</div>
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/MAYag/

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, mouseover will continue to fire when the mouse moves inside the element. I believe your code will cause lots of flicker as the #panel continually toggles. Perhaps you want to use the mouseenter event?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. From the documentation: "The mouseover event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element. Any HTML element can receive this event."

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to `div.close` being inside `div#slide`, which makes the mouseover event fire for close too.